# how to uploads images on a web server. django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to display images on my web site and I can't find my mistake. In other posts I saw that need to upgrade `settings.py`, but I set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL as in example but it doesn't help me.

models:

```
class News(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,
                         verbose_name="Заголовок")
description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Краткое содержание")
posted = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today(), db_index=True, verbose_name="Опубликвана")
tags = TaggableManager(blank=True, verbose_name="Теги")
#user = models.ForeignKey(User)
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-posted']
    verbose_name = "новость"
    verbose_name_plural = "нвости"

def get_image_filename(self, filename):
    title = self.News.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class Images(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(News, default=None, related_name="image")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                          verbose_name="Image")
```

settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`
```

view

```
def news(request):
context = RequestContext(request)
ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Images, form=ImageForm,
                                    extra=3)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewsForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                           queryset=Images.objects.none())
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        post_form = form.save(commit=False)
        #post_form.user = request.user
        post_form.save()
        for forma in formset.cleaned_data:
            try:

                image = forma['image']
                photo = Images(post=post_form, image=image)
                photo.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                     "!!!")
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return redirect("main")
    else:
        print(form.errors, formset.errors)
else:
    form = NewsForm()
    formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Images.objects.none())
try:
    page_num = request.GET.get('page')
except KeyError:
    page_num = 1
images = Images.objects
all_news = News.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(all_news, 10)
try:
    pages = paginator.page(page_num)
except InvalidPage:
    pages = paginator.page(1)
return render_to_response("mainpage.html", {'form': form, 'formset': formset,
                                            'pages': pages, 'news': images}, context)
```

and template

```
{% block content %}
    {% for new in pages %}
    <h2>{{ new.title }}</h2>

    <img src="{{ new.image.url}}">

{% endfor %}


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% include "generic/form.html" %}
<input type="submit" value="создать">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for new in news %}
<h2>{{ new.title }}</h2>
    {% for image in new.image.all %}
    <img src="{{image.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
```

Because post = models.ForeignKey(News, default=None, related_name="image") has many pictures.

Answer (score 0):

This line :

> images = Images.objects

Change it to images = Images.objects.all() and check if it works ?

Comment: i forgot to delete this line. It doesn't do anything.